# Initial setup of hp ProCurve v1910 switch for Small Office?

Tags: hp-procurve

**Resolution:**

Running the <kbd>initialize</kbd> command from the initial menu on the serial port was required to get this switch to work.

I had upgraded the software & tried various settings on the switch but something was set in a non-standard way as delivered. Also from my notes, I copied output from the serial port and noticed the prompt was initially `<HP V1910 Switch>` and after the reset is `<HP>`.

The `Device -> Basic -> System Name` value is what is in the serial prompt's brackets, as it now says *HP*. I know I never would have set the system name as *HP V1910 Switch* And I noticed in the Web UI on the initial page on the right info column under "Product Information" is *HP V1910 Switch*.

Now I'll never assume to get a piece of equipment that has been either factory reset or otherwise unaltered.

---

**Original Question:**
<sub>was *"Does hp ProCurve switch work without being configured?"*</sub>

My office is replacing a 5+ year old Dell 2716 switch with a new hp ProCurve V1910-24G but when I hook it up the same as how the Dell was, there is no routing.

**Does the ProCurve not work "unmanaged"?**

The network I'm improving upon has a [drawing in this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/564410/improvements-for-small-business-network). As I transitioned to the new hp V1910-24G switch from my previous Dell 2716, it appears to not allow any connections between ports. I set the V1910's ip address and networked computers can see the V1910's webserver. I have set up the serial port on my server (via USB adapter) and [found the advanced commands](http://glazenbakje.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/hp-v1910-secret-commando-list-how-to-enable-it/). The wireless router is running Tomato and I have a spreadsheet of MAC addresses and hosts as reported by its DHCP server, so I'm very much on top of what IPs are on which devices.

I've been digging through tutorials for the ProCurve and I figured eventually, I would set up a VLAN for the 2 VoIP boxes and then try to learn if or how its features could improve the windows computers talking to the raid server.

Does this switch act as a router by default?
Will it play nicely with Debian server running IP tables?

**Is this switch overkill and I should go get a 24 port unmanaged switch?**
I've spent so much time on the firewall server and network recabling that it's affecting the business's productivity. If I need to spend a day or two sorting out the hp, I'm inclined to not mess with it any more.

Comment: Bad news: default switch configs rarely work except in the simplest networks; good news: we can help you configure the hp if you add the Dell's config.  BTW, it might be worth replacing iptables with [pfsense](http://pfsense.org/)

Comment: Thanks, pfsense live-CD iso burning now... Thanks for the help, do you know any good "do this for tiny firewalled network" guides?

Comment: pfsense's CD didn't work, so I did the USB install and our work LAN is on it now, thanks! Now to start reading up on how to convince the procurve to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "unmanaged," I think you mean "default configuration."  Yes, it works, but almost certainly not the way you would like it to.  By default, all the ports are up and in a single VLAN (vlan 1). There is no routing enabled. You can type "show interfaces brief" to see the status of all the ports.

You obviously have something more complex on your Dell switch.  If you can let us know how the Dell switch is configured, we can come up with an equivalent for the HP.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for answering. Unless otherwise disturbed, the PowerConnect 27xx family switches come out of the box like a consumer level desktop switch. I tried to find a useful link, but searching is mostly pdfs.

Comment: @ChrisK Can you log into the Dell switch and see what configuration is on it?

Comment: Hi Ron, when in "unmanaged mode", as it is now, there is not a configuration loaded. To log in, you paperclip the managed button, it resets flash (there are no "saving configurations on this switch). But I get that perhaps I could "manage it" to see what it is doing? It was a quite simple UI and no features were enabled.

Comment: If they are both in default configuratoins, they should work the same, i.e. as a switch with all ports active.  So if it's not working that way, something else is going on.  When you plug devices into the HP, do you get link lights?

Comment: Yes. I bet the problem is routing to the gateway. Once the pfsense install is done, I'll get back to this.